# Gnome - Show all windows from all monitors

Tags: gnome, 15.10, multiple-monitors, workspaces

I switch from Unity to Gnome and I miss one function. In Unity when I press workspace button, shows on all monitors all workspaces. This is very useful, when one of my monitors is off. I can move all windows from this monitor to monitor which is on.
How is possible to do this on Gnome 3.16? I can't find any extension.
Please let me know about some solution.